# where is olefileio_pl documentation?

Tags: python, documentation

I am interested in what the olefileio_pl could be able to do (specifically I am trying to write something to a windows 7 sticky note) so I have looked around online for documentation. It doesn't seem like there is any real, detailed docs online. Is there something better then the builtin python help --olefileio_pl or help(olefileio_pl)? It seems that there is no online documentation for the module, and the online docs are typically much better than the builtin ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version 0.40 (renamed olefile) has now experimental write features, that will be completed over time: http://www.decalage.info/python/olefileio

See also http://www.decalage.info/python/olewrite

Alternatively, if your code runs on Windows, you may use the Win32 API with pywin32 for this (look for pythoncom.StgOpenStorageEx).

I also reorganized and improved the documentation, you can find it here:
https://bitbucket.org/decalage/olefileio_pl/wiki

If you have specific questions, you can contact me using this form:
http://decalage.info/contact

Philippe.